# Tableviewcells into specific header sections by classification (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, enums

I'm building a side project that involves a rather complicated table view. I've decided to take inspiration from Producthunt's app and have a header section for each date. **But alas**, this simple implementation is a bit harder than I thought it would be. For reference, I've attached photos below to show you what I'm trying to clone. This is from PH's app:

### Examples

[image: header view one] [image: header view two]

### Implementation

See how there is a Today and Yesterday header section on the top with the date chillin beside it? I've asked peers and some of them suggested to try the [[array]] (array inside of array) approach. Section them out through enums and put them into specific arrays right? This is fine, but after awhile, you can see it getting out of hand. For example, here is some of my code below:

### First, there's an enum for the diffrent date cases

```
enum dateCases {
    case today
    case yesterday
    case twoDaysAgo
    case threeDaysAgo
    case fourDaysAgo
    case fiveDaysAgo
    case lastWeek
    case lastMonth
    case lastYear
    case janurary
    case feburary
    case march
    case april
    case may
    case june
    case july
    case augest
    case september
    case october
    case november
    case december
}
```

### Then there's a struct for each class that needs these arrays in it:

```
struct dateCaseController {
    var todayArray = [Objects]()
    var yesterdayArray = [Objects]()
    var twoDaysAgoArray = [Objects]()
    var threeDaysAgoArray = [Objects]()
    var fourDaysAgoArray = [Objects]()
    var fiveDaysAgoArray = [Objects]()
    var lastWeekArray = [Objects]()
    var lastMonthArray = [Objects]()
    var lastYearArray = [Objects]()
    var januraryArray = [Objects]()
    var feburaryArray = [Objects]()
    var marchArray = [Objects]()
    var aprilArray = [Objects]()
    var mayArray = [Objects]()
    var juneArray = [Objects]()
    var julyArray = [Objects]()
    var augestArray = [Objects]()
    var septemberArray = [Objects]()
    var octoberArray = [Objects]()
    var novemberArray = [Objects]()
    var decemberArray = [Objects]()
}
```

The objects all have dates inside of them we can use to analyze and section out the data. Each instance of this class has this struct.

### After all of that, there's a function to section out the different objects into their specific arrays:

```
 func anilyzeDateForDateCase(){
        for object in objects {
            let dateValue = (Logic for counting how many days has passed)

            switch dateValue {
            case 0:
                print("")
            case 1:
                print("")
            case 2:
                print("")
            case 3:
                print("")
            case 4:
                print("")
            case 5:
                print("")
            case 6:
                print("")
            ect.....
```

### Conclusion

Thats going to be **alot** switch cases. You can tell by going this approach, the code will get out of hand quick. Using this approach would be nice if I had a small number of categories, but that is not the case. Not to mention after that, I will have load the table array according to section. I'm fine with doing that, but I'm wondering if this the correct approach to solving this problem? There has to be a simpler solution. Does anyone have experience with an implementation like this? Thank you.

Comment: You can set all these data by creating json file in your project and use that data source rather than creating these multiple enum and array and dictionary. And mainly it is easy to manage also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly deduce, `enum` is *not* the way to go here. Apart from anything else, it is hard-coding UI choices into your data structures.

Can I suggest something along these lines:

```
import Foundation

// Define a `struct` that describes a date range.
// You may want to have convenience inits that don't just specify "days ago".
// You will create an array of these later...
struct DateRange {
    var latestDaysAgo: Int
    var earliestDaysAgo: Int
    var description: String

    // The important piece of this is that we can check if any given date 
    // is in `self` - we will use this later to `filter` by DateRange
    func isDateInRange(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
        let now = Date()
        let oneDayInSeconds = 86400.0 // 60 * 60 * 24
        let earliestDate = now.addingTimeInterval(Double(-self.earliestDaysAgo) * oneDayInSeconds)
        let latestDate = now.addingTimeInterval(Double(-self.latestDaysAgo) * oneDayInSeconds)
        return (date > earliestDate) && (date <= latestDate)
        // NB - you REALLY want to do this with `Calendar` arithmetic
        // but for clarity of the method, I'm just using 24 hour time differences
    }
}

// Now construct your ranges. These can be extended after testing.
// They can also be overlapping.
let ranges: [DateRange] = [
    DateRange(latestDaysAgo: 0, earliestDaysAgo: 1, description: "Today"),
    DateRange(latestDaysAgo: 1, earliestDaysAgo: 2, description: "Yesterday"),
    DateRange(latestDaysAgo: 2, earliestDaysAgo: Int.max, description: "Earlier"),
]

// This is whatever event struct you need - but they include the date
struct Event {
    var date: Date
    var payload: String // or whatever struct you want
}
// Create some random test data
let events: [Event]  = [
    Event(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(-100), payload: "abc"),
    Event(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(-1000), payload: "abc"),
    Event(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(-100000), payload: "abc"),
    Event(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(-1000000), payload: "abc"),
]

// Now, the clever piece is combining `flatMap` & `filter` to get your sections:
let sections: [(DateRange, [Event])] = ranges.flatMap({
    (dr: DateRange) in
    let qualifyingEvents = events.filter({ dr.isDateInRange($0.date) })
    return (dr, qualifyingEvents)
})
// Note that the order of ranges in `sections` is the same as the 
// order that you chose in `ranges`.

// Check the sections are correct.
for (dr, es) in sections {
    print("'\(dr.description)' has \(es.count) entries")
}

/* Output:
 'Today' has 2 entries
 'Yesterday' has 1 entries
 'Earlier' has 1 entries
*/
```

You can now drive your `UITableViewDataSource` with `sections`. For example:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].1.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section].0.description
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyCellID")

    let payload = sections[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row].payload

    cell.textLabel?.text = payload // or whatever...
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly detailed review! I will try to implement and then get back to you!

Comment: You're very welcome! An entertaining little problem in data structure design! I'm sure it's not the only solution...